# Is the listModels request limited to the number of returned records by default?

Tags: clarifai

For the following call
`client.listModels(ListModelsRequest.newBuilder().build());`
will all of the models be returned or just some subset?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Clarifai Swagger UI](https://api.clarifai.com/api-doc/#/V2/ListModels), the default page size is 128, so only the first 128 models will be returned. If you wish to get all the models, then you need to paginate it using `page` parameter.